# Is this the correct method to unblind an RSA signature?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, blind-signature

I'm working through the wiki on RSA blind signatures. Here are my methods as I understand them, where r is the blinding factor, m is the message, d is the private key, e is the exponent, and n is public key:

```
public BigInteger sign(BigInteger m, BigInteger d, BigInteger n)
{
    return m.modPow(d, n); 
}

public BigInteger blindMessage(BigInteger m, BigInteger r, BigInteger e, BigInteger n)
{
    return m.multiply(r.modPow(e, n));
}

public BigInteger unblindMessage(BigInteger m, BigInteger r, BigInteger n)
{
    return m.multiply(r.modPow(BigInteger.ONE.negate(), n));  
}
```

I've verified my actual RSA implementation works already; however, there's a difference between the "normal" signature and the blinded signature. I'm worried I didn't code the equations correctly, because I've never worked with BigIntegers before.

My demo code is:

```
    RSA rsa = new RSA();
    RSAobject alice = rsa.keygen(32);
    RSAobject bank = rsa.keygen(32);;
    BigInteger message = new BigInteger("123");
    System.out.println("Message: " + message.toString());
    BigInteger cyphertext = rsa.encrypt(message, alice.n, alice.e);
    System.out.println("Cyphertext: " + cyphertext.toString());
    BigInteger decrypted = rsa.decrypt(cyphertext, alice.d, alice.n);
    System.out.println("Plaintext: " + decrypted.toString());
    BigInteger normalSign = rsa.sign(message, bank.d, bank.n);
    System.out.println("Normal Signature: " + normalSign.toString());
    BigInteger blindingFactor = rsa.getBlindingFactor(alice.n);
    System.out.println("Blinding factor: " + blindingFactor.toString());
    BigInteger blindedMessage = rsa.blindMessage(message, blindingFactor, alice.e, alice.n);
    System.out.println("Blinded Message: " + blindedMessage.toString());
    BigInteger blindedMessageSignature = rsa.sign(blindedMessage, bank.d, bank.n);
    System.out.println("Blinded Message Signature: " + blindedMessageSignature.toString());
    BigInteger unblindedMessageSignature = rsa.unblindMessage(blindedMessage, blindingFactor, alice.n);
    System.out.println("Unblinded Message Signature: " + unblindedMessageSignature.toString());
```

And it outputs the following:

```
Message: 123
Cyphertext: 22707724
Plaintext: 123
Normal Signature: 13584112
Blinding factor: 14036619
Blinded Message: 689947713
Blinded Message Signature: 7031325
Unblinded Message Signature: 20354580078429051
```

Am I doing anything "wrong" here, or is that how they're supposed to look?

Comment: Your multiplications also need be followed by a `.mod(n)`

Comment: I thought modPow already took care of the mod(n) aspect?

Comment: No, it only takes care of it for that particular method. Every multiply, addition, etc. also needs to be taken mod n.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is . What does *"... there's a difference between...[a] and [b]"* mean? You should clearly state the problem. I believe you are supposed to add the blinding value before the private key operation, and remove it after the private key operation. It is not supposed to persist. You are also missing several important elements to a signature scheme. You should avoid using the code as-is, and probably read [Bernstein's paper](https://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf).

Comment: I'm literally taking my info from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature#cite_note-GoldwasserBellare-2 - And what I mean by the difference between [a] and [b] is that the signature as if I signed without a blinding factor is vastly different from the blinded, then unblinded, signature at the bottom of my output listing. Aren't they supposed to be the same?